# загрузка фото из баз данных

Tags: php, html, css

Так у меня простая система для upload-а на базу данных потом тут отображается из баз данных а как сделать чтобы можно было скачать изображание?

```
<?php
    require_once('dbConfig.php');
    $upload_dir = 'uploads/';
    if(isset($_GET['delete'])){
        $id = $_GET['delete'];

        //select old photo name from database
        $sql = "select photo from images where id = ".$id;
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $photo = $row['photo'];
            unlink($upload_dir.$photo);
            //delete record from database
            $sql = "delete from images where id=".$id;
            if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
                header('location:index.php');
            }
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.gallery picture {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.gallery img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #2590EB;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.wrapper .file-upload {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2590EB 50%, #FFFFFF 50%);
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  transition: all 1s;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 100px;
}
.wrapper .file-upload a {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.wrapper .file-upload:hover {
  background-position: 0 -100%;
  color: #2590EB;
}
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    .wrapper .file-upload {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2590EB 50%, #FFFFFF 50%);
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  transition: all 1s;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 50px;
}

}

</style>
    <title>Uploadimage</title>
        <link href="./css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <h3 class="navbar-brand">PHP upload image</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="file-upload">
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<a href="add.php"> </a>
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
                $sql = "select * from images";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            ?>

            <div class="gallery">

  <picture>
                                            <img src="<?php echo $upload_dir.$row['photo'] ?>"  >

  </picture>
</div>

                        <a class="btn btn-info" href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>Deyiw sekli
                        </a><br>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="index.php?delete=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" onclick="return confirm('100% sikdir elirsen?')">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>Sikdir ele
                        </a>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="index.php?download=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" >
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>Yukle bled
                        </a>

            <?php
                    }
                }
            ?>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример из [официальной](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.readfile.php) документации
Ты можешь это сделать в виде хэндлера, куда будет передаваться путь к файлу (или идентификатор его, а потом в скрипте получать путь), а этот скрипт (скажем будет называться download.php) уже будет отдавать сам файл пользователю. Таким образом у тебя ссылки в галерее будут ссылаться на этот хэндлер, а он в свою очередь отдавать.

```
 <?php
    $file = 'monkey.gif';

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: можно конкретнее не понял очень

Comment: И можно кое что другое спросить на локальном сервере этот код работал все текстовое содержимое и  фото показывались а захотел на веб сайт это фото нету а текст содержимое работает это из за upload_dir думаю помогите?